# Export Google Sheets as CSV/JSON via URL in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

My Android app connects to a Google account and should retrieve a Google Sheets file from Google Drive as CSV or JSON, either works.

I'm using the following URL structure:

```
sheetURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"
    + sheetID + "fields=contentHints%2Fthumbnail%2FmimeType%2CcopyRequiresWriterPermission"
    + "%2CcreatedTime%2CfileExtension%2CfullFileExtension%2Cid%2Ckind%2ClastModifyingUser%2CmimeType%2CmodifiedByMeTime%2CmodifiedTime%2Cname%2CownedByMe&key=" + APP_API_KEY;
```

and the getter code is as follows:

```
private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        Log.d("DOWNLOADURL", "URL TO CONNECT: " + url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
        //Log.d("DOWNLOAD_URL", "CONTENT_AS_STRING: " + contentAsString);

        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been looking for this answer for many hours. I can get all the metadata specified by the URL except the file itself. Probably missing something obvious. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: The Sheets API can return object data (via client library) or JSON (via REST API).